# How to organize the output of the list of list in R

Tags: r

Suppose this is my list of list (I would like to organize the result as my data contains more than `40` results and it is difficult for me to organize them manually).

```
s <- c(1,2,3)
ss <- c(4,5,6)
S <- list(s,ss)
h <- c(4,8,7)
hh <- c(0,3,4)
H <- list(h,hh)
HH <- list(S,H)




  names1 <- c("First","Second")

lapply(setNames(HH, paste0(names1, '_Model')), function(x) 
  setNames(x, paste0('Res_', seq_along(x))))

#$First_Model
#$First_Model$Res_1
#[1] 1 2 3

#$First_Model$Res_2
#[1] 4 5 6


#$Second_Model
#$Second_Model$Res_1
#[1] 4 8 7

#$Second_Model$Res_2
#[1] 0 3 4
```

I would like to have the result similar to the following:

```
 #$First_Model
#$First_Model$Res_1
#[1] 1 2 3
 
  
  #$Second_Model
#$Second_Model$Res_1
#[1] 4 8 7

   #$First_Model$Res_2
#[1] 4 5 6
    
    #$Second_Model$Res_2
#[1] 0 3 4
```

Comment: Please you clarify your objective. Do you mean you want to rearrange the lists so that all `Res_1` appears before all `Res_2`, then followed by `Res_3`, `Res_4`, etc.?

Comment: @LC-datascientist Yes. That what I would like to have. Thanks for your comment and try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in question is how to rearrange the nested list from "Model No. > Results No." to "Results No. > Model No."

I was going for something similar to [Wimpel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67818005/6288065).

```r
Res_no <- seq_along(HH[[1]]) # results elements

lapply(setNames(Res_no, paste0("Res_", Res_no)), function(x) 
    lapply(setNames(HH, paste0(names1, '_Model')), `[[`, x)
)
```

**Output**

```
#$Res_1
#$Res_1$First_Model
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$Res_1$Second_Model
#[1] 4 8 7
#
#
#$Res_2
#$Res_2$First_Model
#[1] 4 5 6
#
#$Res_2$Second_Model
#[1] 0 3 4
```

The base of this solution is to extract the *x*-th element of the nested list (seen in the inner `lapply()` function of the code). You can do this with `lapply` or `purrr:map`, as described [here](https://statisticsglobe.com/select-first-element-of-nested-list-in-r).

The outer `lapply()` function lets you repeat it for all the "Results No."

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
# From your code, create a list L
L <- lapply(setNames(HH, paste0(names1, '_Model')), function(x) 
  setNames(x, paste0('Res_', seq_along(x))))
# get all x-th elements from the list, and add them to new list L2
L2 <- lapply( 1:length(L[[1]]), function(x) {
  lapply(L, "[[", x)  
})
# set names of L2
names(L2) <- names(L[[1]])
```

**output**

```
# $Res_1
# $Res_1$First_Model
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $Res_1$Second_Model
# [1] 4 8 7
# 
# 
# $Res_2
# $Res_2$First_Model
# [1] 4 5 6
# 
# $Res_2$Second_Model
# [1] 0 3 4
```